# Is there a way to make a timestamp for the last updated field on a record in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, records

Is there a way to add a flag in a mysql table where I can put a timestamp of the last updated field with the name of the filed in every record?

Comment: can you explain it bit more?

Comment: Can you not just add a column called LastUpdated or something similar to that and have it set the current_timestamp for all updates to that row?

Comment: Yes, but i want to know which was the field that was last updated in every row and not the last updated row.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE` ADD `LastUpdated` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ` Add in another extra column to go with it "last updated field" and have your sql queries populate that too. between the 2 columns you have what you want

Comment: What if it was more than one at a time? TBH we would need to know why (more context) to give the best advice

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal with a trigger. You don't have to take care of updating the column which indicates what was updated anymore.

See this example:

```
drop table if exists foo;
create table foo(a int, b int, c int, 
                 modified timestamp on update current_timestamp, 
                 whichOne varchar(255)
                );
insert into foo (a, b, c) values (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6);

drop trigger if exists foomod;
delimiter $$
create trigger foomod before update on foo 
for each row
begin
set @cols = '';
if old.a != new.a then
set @cols = CONCAT(@cols, ', ', 'a');
elseif old.b != new.b then
set @cols = CONCAT(@cols, ', ', 'b');
elseif old.c != new.c then
set @cols = CONCAT(@cols, ', ', 'c');
end if;
set new.whichOne = @cols;
end $$
delimiter ;

select * from foo;
```

Result:

```
a   b   c   modified    whichOne
1   2   3       
4   5   6
```

---

```
update foo set b = 10 where b = 2;

select * from foo;
```

Result:

```
a   b   c   modified    whichOne
1   10  3   2013-06-27 12:45:29Z    , b
4   5   6
```

Of course there's room for improvement, but you get the point, right?

Comment: Since he was struggling with such a basic concept a trigger is probably way way way beyond the knowledge level here.  But I like the solution so I'll +1 you for it

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE` ADD LastUpdatedColumns TEXT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE` ADD LastUpdated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Then when doing your update queries its something like this

```
$fieldsupdated = "field1, field2, field3";
$sql = "UPDATE `YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE` SET LastUpdatedColumns='$fieldsupdated';
```

Then if you want to report in future on the last time/date a certain column was edited you could do something like

```
$sql = "SELECT LastUpdated FROM `YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE` WHERE LastUpdatedColumns LIKE '%field1%'
```

There's better ways of doing it than a broad LIKE I think but I can't for the life of me think of it off the top of my head today.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to manually create the $fieldsupdated variable in my example but I assume you're doing some form of input validation etc anyway so you can create that string within those validatation cases